How can I see that this surface is indeed closed
I recently came across a proof of the weak maximum principle (if a function $u:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is such that $\nabla^2u=0$ and $u$ has only isolated critical points, then they can't be nor a maximum nor a minimum).
The proof basically starts assuming there is a critical point ($\nabla u(x_o)=0$) which is a maximum and finding a neighborhood $V$ of $x_o$ (a ball around $x_o$ of some radius $\delta>0$)  where $\nabla u(y)\neq0$ for $y\in V\backslash\{x_o\}$ and $u(y)\geq u(x_o)-\varepsilon$.
The claim is that $S=\{y\in V: u(y)=u(x_o)-\varepsilon\}$ is a closed smooth surface. I get that the 'smooth' part comes from the Implicit Fctn Thm but I can't really see why it is closed
My idea is that since $\nabla u(y)\neq 0$ in S, then the surface should be smooth everywhere (again, Implicit Function Theorem), and since it is contained in a ball of some radius, then it should be closed but I'm not sure if this is 100% correct
Any help?

Maybe they are using a nonstandard notion of a closed surface. The usual definition is that it is compact and has empty boundary. With this definition, the claim is false, you can take any nonconstant linear function $u$.

Level sets of continuous functions are topologically closed subspaces. What are they using here?

The proof just says that S is a closed surface and through this, it then uses divergence thm to get a contradiction

Did you understand the answer?

Yess, I'm new using this and forgot marking your answer. Thanksss

Sorry, I did not read the question carefully enough at first. Here is a proof.
Without loss of generality, $V=B(x_0, R)$ for some $R>0$ and $u$ does not take the value $u_0$ on $\partial V$. (Such $R$ exists since $x_0$ is an isolated local maximum of $u$.) Suppose that there is no $\epsilon>0$ such that the intersection of $\partial V$ with  $S=\{u= u_0-\epsilon\}$ is nonempty. Take a sequence $\epsilon_n\to 0+$ and points $x_n\in  \partial V$ such that $u(x_n)=  u_0-\epsilon_n$. Then, after passing to a subsequence, we can assume that $x_n\to x\in \partial V$ and (by continuity) $u(x)=u_0$. But this is a contradiction. Hence,  $S\cap V$ is compact and (by the regularity assumption) smooth subsurface in $V$, as required.
